# Float left/right makes gap on window resize

Tags: css, css-float

On my site I have three divs, one header, one main content and a sidebar on the right side.
The sidebar is the actual problem. I want that the sidebar always sticks to the right side of the browser window and if the user resizes the window so that the width is lower than the main and sidebar, the sidebar stops at the left edge of the main content.

When the user first access the webpage and press the "green, maximize window button" on a Mac atleast, the window should resize so that the main content and sidebar are placed edge to edge with no gap.

With my code everything works fine except that when I resize the window to the smallest width possible and then press the maximize window button, there is a 16px gap between the two divs.

My code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="container">        
        <div id="main">
        <p> Left </p>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
        <p> Right </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
body{
margin:0 0;
min-width:606px;
}

#header {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#00FF00;
    height:100px;
}

#container{
    min-width: 865px;
    min-height: 50px;
}

#main {
    float:left;
    min-width: 622px;
    background:#FF0000;
}

#sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:243px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background:#0000FF;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCjVF/1/show)  (*In the Address Bar, remove **`/show/`** to access jsFiddle Edit Page.*)

Instead of dealing with `float` for your layout, use `table` and `table-cell` which allows your goal to be realized. Tested and working in Firefox, Chrome, IE8 on a XP machine.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">Header</div>

<div id="container">        

    <div id="main">
      <p>Main</p>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 865px;          /* Optional: This size is the same as #container width. */
}

#container{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 865px;
    height: 50px;
}

#main {
    display: table-cell;
    /*min-width: 622px;*/     /* Not needed since #container min-width less #sidebar width will use remainder percentage space (since #container is set at 100%) */
    height: 100%;             /* Maximum height is set via #container height */
    background: red;
}

#sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 243px;            /* The fixed width of the sidebar */
    height: 100%;            /* Maximum height is set via #container height */
    background: aqua;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, I want to have a max-width of the main div. I just want to get rid of the gap at the default size of the browser window.

Comment: In my original code there was a gap when resizing the browser window to the "default" size. I want both divs to be side by side at default size and have the sidebar edge to edge with the right side of the browser window. Then if you make the window bigger, the sidebar sticks to the right side of the browser window and the main div stays at 622px. If you make the window smaller then default, the sidebar stays at the right edge of the main div and doesn't move below it.

Comment: Though, maybe that is different on different resolutions, OS and browsers?

Comment: I don't see 16px gap with your original code. I don't know what "default" size means. To be sure, your CSS is not clear on the required `min-width` since `body` has it smaller than `#container`. The largest `min-width` for any item becomes the `min-width` the browser uses. Ref: `#main`, your example has `min-width` yet your comment is for `max-width`. Please define `side-by-side` since I consider that *touching objects*. I think what's needed is your jsFiddle that reproduces the issue or explain how I can improve mine. That said, this is [**jsFiddle v2: Floats**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCjVF/16/)

Comment: Well never mind the "default size" thing, cause I think that's something that has todo with resolution of the screen. I will leave it the way it was but I've removed some unnecessary stuff that I don't need. Thanks for your help anyway! :)

Comment: Was the **jsFiddle v2: Floats** of any use?

Comment: It does pretty much what I had from the beginning, so yes! :) Also I've learned more about CSS code from you :D